# Next button is grey

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, django-1.5

I have installed eclipse(indego)/python(2.7)/django(1.5.5) properly on a ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
but when I start a new pydev project and give a new project name,
the 'next' button and 'finish' button are both grey, 
and no error are shown in create diaglog box.

How to create a django project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix.

Apparently, what caused the problem is that I have included the site-packages directory from a virtual environment into the PYTHONPATH of interpreters. After removing it, the grayed out buttons went normal.